# How can I find keccak 256 hash in Python

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography, keccak

I am using Python 2.7 and need to find `keccak` hash for solidity events. However I don't see a default lib for the same.

I installed `sha3` but it doesn't seem to provide this functionality. Tried [pysha3](https://github.com/tiran/pysha3) with below code

```
  import sha3
  k = sha3.keccak_512()
  k.update('age')
  k.hexdigest()
```

But got the error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'keccak_512'
```

sha3 doesn't have this module indeed

```
>>> dir(sha3)
['SHA3224', 'SHA3256', 'SHA3384', 'SHA3512', 'SHAKE128', 'SHAKE256', '_SHA3Base', '_SHAKEBase', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_sha3', 'binascii', 'copy', 'hashlib', 'sha3_224', 'sha3_256', 'sha3_384', 'sha3_512', 'shake128', 'shake256']
```

Comment: Did you even check the official website of **Keccak** (spelling!)?

Comment: was a typo due to touch type.

Comment: Did you install a native sha3 library and expect it to just work? If so, please take a look at the python wrapper [pysha3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3).

Comment: installed `pysha3` but it doesn't seem to work. Gives error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'keccak_512'
`

Comment: @KompjoeFriek I am naive in cyrptography, python 3.6 suggest to have something related to `keccak`. I was looking just looking for something pythonic.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the relevant python code including the imports, a mention of the pysha3 wrapper and the error you got.

Comment: why a downvote?

Comment: Can you please also include the output of `dir(sha3)` to your question. It looks like you ran into this issue: https://github.com/tiran/pysha3/issues/8. However, it does not mention which python version is used there. Your code does work python 3.6.x (only difference is it requires a byte literal for `update()`, just like all of hashlib does).

Comment: `pysha3` is working, `sha3` was overriding it. Original implementer should give a different import name.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. [**pycryptodome**](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io)  `pip install pycryptodome`

   ```
    from Crypto.Hash import keccak
    k = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
    k.update('age')
    print k.hexdigest()
   ```
2. [**pysha3**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysha3) `pip install pysha3`

   ```
   import sha3
   k = sha3.keccak_256()
   k.update('age')
   print k.hexdigest()
   ```

**Please note**:

1. For `python3` the strings need to be passed in binary `k.update(b'age')`
2. If you want to find a new hash you need to initialize `k` again otherwise it will update the value on top of the existing one.

If you have both `sha3` and `pysha3`, it won't work, since `import sha3` will default to `sha3` lib.

Online handy [**tool**](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html)

Comment: The "online handy tool" and the python code return separate hashes. For `k.update("0")
print (k.hexdigest())` it returns the same than the website `044852b2a670ade5407e78fb2863c51de9fcb96542a07186fe3aeda6bb8a116` but for "1" it's different. Why does it in the one case accept the input as a number but in the other case seems to take the ""?

Comment: For the ppl trying to use this for ethereum: hashlib does not return the correct hashes, pycryptodome is the one you want!

Comment: @garg10may and for a compatible pypy answer?

Comment: FYI @garg10may pycryptodome example needs to be passed a binary string (i.e. `b'age'`) instead of a string

Comment: This is because you are using `python3`. For `python2` it will work. I have now highlighted the same in answer.

Comment: @Senju sorry for replying after a year, but you need to perform the sha3.keccak_256() step again for a new hash value, I am assuming you did k.update("1") step after finding the hash of 0 so essentially you were finding hash of 01 hence they were not matching. You can match them with 01 on the tool they should match

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sha3' after pip install sha3

Comment: pls use `pip install pysha3`